# QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called in a QTreeWidget derived class

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter, qtreewidget

I have a class, `MyTree`, which derived from `QTreeWidget` and

```
void MyTree::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
}
```

causes to raise the following issue,

> QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
>
> QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1

Could someone please help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of classes that inherit from [`QAbstractScrollArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html) as [`QTreeWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html) and your `MyTree` the painting is not given directly in the widget but in the [`viewport()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport) as indicated by the docs:

> **void QAbstractScrollArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) Reimplemented
>   from QFrame::paintEvent().**
>
> This event handler can be reimplemented in a subclass to receive paint
>   events (passed in event), for the viewport() widget.
>
> Note: If you open a painter, make sure to open it on the viewport().

So the solution is as follows:

```
void MyTree::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(viewport());
}
```